# How to remove duplicate record using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have list of list and want to remove duplicate from list.
Data is stored in list format say `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> tableData`
if we consider it as table value, 
parent list is for rows and child list is values of every column.
Now I want to delete all duplicate rows. from below table value A is duplicate.

```
List<List<string>> ls = new List<List<string>>();
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "A" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "2", "B" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "3", "C" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "4", "A" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "5", "A" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "6", "D" });
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> tableData = ls;

var abc = tableData.SelectMany(p => p).Distinct();   ///not work
```

after operation, I want **abc** should be exactly **tableData** format

```
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "A" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "2", "B" });
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "3", "C" });   
ls.Add(new List<string>() { "6", "D" });
```

Comment: What is `PropertyData`? It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating what your data looks like.

Comment: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PropertyData>> tableData contains complete table.where each parent list as row and each child list as columns for that row.

Comment: @jon, I have changed class.

Comment: @Ehsan, yes its list of list.

Comment: It's still unclear what you've got, to be honest. A short but complete example would be *much* clearer.

Comment: Is your `list` actually an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> tableData` or is it `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PropertyData>> tableData`?

Comment: There's a distinct function in linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tableData.GroupBy(q => q.Skip(1).First()).Select(q => q.First())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) passing in an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assuming you actually have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PropertyData>>`.

For example:

```
var items = tableData.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct(new TableComparer());
```

And the comparer:

```
public class TableComparer : IEqualityComparer<PropertyData>
{
    public bool Equals(PropertyData x, PropertyData y)
    {
        return x.id == y.id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PropertyData pData)
    {
        return pData.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If it's just an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, you can use `Distinct()` without the overload:

```
var items = tableData.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

Though your question lacks clarity..

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinctValues = tableData.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

This will flatten your list of lists and select the distinct set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
         List<List<string>> ls=new List<List<string>>();
         ls.Add(new List<string>(){"Hello"});
         ls.Add(new List<string>(){"Hello"});
         ls.Add(new List<string>() { "He" });
         IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> tableData = ls;
         var abc = tableData.SelectMany(p => p).Distinct();
```

O/P is

Hello

He

Comment: var abc = tableData.Select(q => q.ElementAt(1).Distinct());

Comment: No, that's not it either.

Comment: No, It doesn't work. It will not give distinct record.